# Cannot call chown inside Docker container (Docker for Windows)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am attempting to use the [official Mongo dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/21a6f6cf3eff13a39b20c86224730a29823370ca/3.2/Dockerfile) to boot up a database, I am using the `-v` command to map a local directory to `/data` inside the container.

As part of the `Dockerfile`, it attempts to chown this directory to the user mongodb:

```
RUN mkdir -p /data/db /data/configdb \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db /data/configdb
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

However, this fails with the following command:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Permission denied
```

What I am doing wrong here? I cannot find any documentation around this - surely the container should have full permissions to the mapped directory, as it was explicitly passed in the docker run command:

```
docker run -d --name mongocontainer -v R:\mongodata:/data/db -p 3000:27017 mongo:latest
```

Comment: commands that appear in a Dockerfile RUN statement are not run at the time that a 'docker run' happens. The Dockerfile RUN statement happens during image creation when the 'docker build' commands run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have similar issues illustrating the same error message in [mongo issues 68](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/68) or [issue 74](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74)

> The host machine volume directory cannot be under `/Users` (or `~`). Try:

```
docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v /var/lib/boot2docker/my-mongodb-data/:/data/db -d mongo --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

The [PR 470](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/470/files) adds:

> **WARNING**: because MongoDB uses memory mapped files it is not possible to use it through vboxsf to your host ([vbox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819)).
>
> **VirtualBox shared folders are not supported by MongoDB** (see [docs.mongodb.org](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories) and related [jira.mongodb.org](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8600) bug).
>
> This means that it is not possible with the default setup using Docker Toolbox to run a MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host.

Comment: Understood - thank you for your comprehensive answer.