# Change file permissions in mounted folder inside docker container on Windows Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-toolbox, docker-for-windows

**Disclaimer/Edit 2**

Some years later, for everyone reading this question - If you are on Windows and want to use docker with linux containers, I highly recommend not using docker for windows at all and instead starting the entire docker environment inside a VM altogether. This Ext3 NTFS issue will break your neck on so many different levels that installing docker-machine might not even be worth the effort.

---

**Edit:**

I am using [`docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) which starts a boot2docker instance inside a Virtualbox VM with a shared folder on /c/Users from which you can mount volumes into your containers. The permissions of said volumes are the ones the question is about. The VMs are stored under /c/Users/tom/.docker/

I chose to use the `docker-machine` Virtualbox workflow over Hyper-V because I need VBox in my daily workflow and running Hyper-V and Virtualbox together on one system is not possible due to incompabilities between different Hypervisors.

**Original question**

I am currently trying to set up PHPMyAdmin in a container on windows but I can't change the permissions of the `config.inc.php` file.

I found: [Cannot call chown inside Docker container (Docker for Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834349/cannot-call-chown-inside-docker-container-docker-for-windows) and thought this might be somewhat related but it appears to apply only to MongoDB.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"

    services:
      pma:
        image: (secrect company registry)/phpmyadmin
        ports: 
          - 9090:80
        volumes:
          - /c/Users/tom/projects/myproject/data/var/www/public/config.inc.php:/var/www/public/config.inc.php
```

now, when I `docker exec -it [container] bash` and change in the mounted directory, I try to run `chmod` on the `config.inc.php` but for some reason, it fails **silently**.

```
root@22a4bag43245: ls -la config.inc.php
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Aug 11 15:11 config.inc.php
root@22a4bag43245: chmod 655 config.inc.php
root@22a4bag43245: ls -la config.inc.php
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Aug 11 15:11 config.inc.php
```

Considering the linked answer, I thought I could just move the volume out of my Userhome but then vbox doesn't mount the folder at all.

How do I change the file permissions of `/var/www/public/config.inc.php` persistently?

Comment: Is `/c/Users/tom/projects/myproject/data/var/www/public/config.inc.php` a file or a folder?

Comment: config.inc.php is a file

Comment: but it doesn't matter whether I mount folders or files as volumes, I am not able to change the permissions

Comment: found another link with the same issue: https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-change-owner-and-permissions-of-a-volume-inside-container/26797

Comment: You might want to try mounting the parent directory instead of the single file. Changing permissions on a _mount_ point could be something special (say: impossible).

Comment: @gesellix I tried both already. I did some research and it's probably related to the inherently different permission models of nfts and ext3 since I am trying to mount a folder/file from my windows host into a debian container. My current workaround for persisting my config is to push it to a docker data volume and mount that instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem of not being able to change ownership even after using `chown`. And as I  [researched](https://superuser.com/questions/1237368/ownership-remains-unchanged-after-sudo-chown-in-ubuntu), it was because of NTFS volumes being mounted inside ext filesystem. So I used another approach.

The volumes internal to docker are free from these problems. So you can mount your file on internal docker volume and then create a hard symlink to that file inside your local folder wherever you want:

```
sudo ln $(docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' <project_name>_<volume_name>) <absolute_path_of_destination>
```

This way you can have your files in desired place, inside docker and without any permission issues, and you will be able to modify the contents of file as in the normal volume mount due to hard symlink.

[Here](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/develop/deploy.sh#L156) is a working implementation of this process which mounts and links a directory. In case you wanna know about the details, see `possible fix` section in [issue](https://github.com/reactome/container/issues/29#issuecomment-320079668).

**EDIT**

Steps to implement this approach:

1. Mount the concerned file in internal docker-volume(also known as `named volumes`).
2. Before making hardlink, make sure volumes and concerned file are present there. To ensure this, you should have run your container at least once before or if you want to automate this file creation, you can include a docker run which creates the required files and exits.

   `docker run --rm -itd \
   -v "<Project_name>_<volume_name>:/absolute/path" \
   <image> bash -c "touch /absolute/path/<my_file>"`

This docker run will create volumes and required files. Here, `container` is my project name, by default, it is the name of the folder in which project is present and `<volume_name>` is the same as one which we want to use in our original container. `<image>` can be the same one which is already being used in your original containers.

3. Create a hardlink in your OS to the actual file location on your system. You can find the file location using `docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' <project_name>_<volume_name>/<my_file>`. Linux users can use `ln` in terminal and windows users can use `mklink` in command prompt.

In step 3 we have not used `/absolute/path` since the `<volume_name>` refers to that location already, and we just need to refer to the file.

Comment: this approach looks promising. I'll try it and get back to you, thank you

Comment: wait, I can't hardlink on my host OS since it's windows. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: This was for linux OS, for windows you can use `mklink`. More details [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Comment: so basically I create a hardlink from my windows host into a datavolume and mount that volume in my container?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I'll update the detailed steps in my answer.

Comment: `mklink /h /d '/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/myproject_data-volume/_data/config.inc.php' 
 \Users\tom\projects\myproject\data\var\www\public\config.inc.php` returns "invalid Option - "mnt" on cmd.

Comment: I also tried `for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (docker volume inspect --format '{{.Mountpoint}}' "myproject_data-volume/config.inc.php") do mklink /h /d %i \Users\tom\projects\myproject\mydata\config.inc.php` which did not work either.

Comment: I have created a data-volume containing a file beforehand but the `docker volume inspect` command returns a unix path.

Comment: well, combining `/h` and `/d` in `mklink` is not supposed to work together anyways but even with valid syntax I can't hardlink a unixpath to a windowspath

Comment: Ah, I [found](https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277/5) that volume path on windows and mac is different than the actual path shown by `volume inspect`

Comment: [Path in windows](https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/3?u=ayushya) is `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual`

Comment: I'm not using Hyper-V but virtualbox driver and `docker-machine`. Is there still a chance to get this working somehow?

Comment: If you can update your question with the details of the process, then maybe we could look for another approach. Might be that your files are accessible in some other way.

Comment: what process exactly?

Comment: I am not sure about virtual-box driver, are you running the containers in virtual box? The process I wanna know about is that how you are accessing real files on host and how your docker is running. More relevant part would be, where your docker is storing its files?

Comment: are you okay with me moving this discussion to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152192/discussion-between-ayushya-and-tom-m).

Comment: A hard link can't cross file system boundaries so this wouldn't work for file shared from Windows > Linux

Answer (score 8):

Try one of the following:

1. If you can rebuild the image  image:  `image: (secrect company registry)/docker-stretchimal-apache2-php7-pma` then inside the docker file, add the following

   `USER root
   RUN chmod 655 config.inc.php`

Then you can rebuild the image and push it to the registry, and what you were doing should work. This should be your preferred solution, as you don't want to be manually changing the permissions everytime you start a new container

2. Try to exec using the user root explicitly

   `docker exec -it -u root [container] bash`

Comment: I am unable to change permissions of directories/volumes mounted from windows host into docker container. AFAIK, 1. will `chmod` the `confic.inc.php` **inside** the image which will get overridden by my mounted confic.inc.php. 2. does not work. Even if I `-u root`, the permissions still won't change when I `chmod`.

Comment: @TomM can you provide the docker file for the image?

Comment: no, sorry. But it does not work with images from the official registry either so I doubt the image is at fault

Comment: Dockerfile is executed (built) before volume is mounted, you can't change permissions in mounted volume this way.