# Unable to change file permissions in bind mounted directory in docker container

Tags: docker

I have a working folder in Windows 7. The directory is bind-mounted in a ubuntu docker container as:

```
docker run -it -v /path/to/windows:/path/to/ubuntu bash
```

Everything works as intended, I'm able to edit files in windows and execute the updated files in ubuntu. But, I see that files in the mounted directory are having permission as 777. For example, when I create a file in the directory as:

```
install -m 600 /dev/null file
```

the permissions of the new "file" is set to be 777 instead of 600.

How can I set file permission as expected? (I have gone through similar questions like [Change file permissions in mounted folder inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635937/change-file-permissions-in-mounted-folder-inside-docker-container) but didn't from its comments, it seems the solution discussed there didn't really help) Can someone give a simpler explanation?

Comment: Are you using Virtualbox to run the VM? Can you change the permissions of the Windows files on the Linux host outside of the container? Are you doing any userns mapping in Docker?

Comment: I'm using docker toolbox in windows 7. Yes, I'm able to change its permission in the host machine, i.e. Windows. Rest of the configuration is by default, hence no additional mappings.